# I want to show progress during the process

Tags: label, progress

I want to show progress during the process. But the program hangs and progress shows nothing, until the process ends. How to show each item in the label. (each operation with file takes a long time (Hard job))
   I'm using visual studio 2008. VB.net or C# code

```
  Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("*.ggpf")

    For Each filename As String In files
        Label1.Text = filename


        do 
        ......
        ...... Some write operations with file goes here 

        loop 




    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a progress bar tool and these are the basic properties for that :

```
ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
ProgressBar1.Maximum = FileSize
ProgressBar1.Value = BytesSent
```

If you want to pass the progress to a dialog or label :

```
Label1.Text = String.Format("{0}%", ((ProgressBar1.Value / ProgressBar1.Maximum) * 100).ToString("F2"))
```

Comment: When I have a big loop and want to update label with filename for example. Filenames are in array. It writes the first Item and then last when process ends.

Comment: @GGSoft so you want to display the File Names from first to last as the progress goes? Show me your code.